# Proper way to install JVCL 3.47 on XE3

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe3, jvcl, jedi-code-library

I am trying to install JVCL 3.47 on a Delphi XE3 instance but I failed twice; I know that first I must install JCL; When I run Install.bat located in the jcl folder I get this error: "Windows cannot find '..\bin\JediInstaller.exe' ...;

I looked into bin folder but indeed JediInstaller.exe is not there; So I have opened  the project JediInstaller located in "..\JVCL347CompleteJCL241-Build4571\jcl\jcl\install" and compiled it and then I started JediInstaller and installed JCL; Afer I tried to install JVCL again with opening the installer project and compiling it but again it returned an error that JCL is not installed and I don't know way because I have it installed;

When I installed JVCL 3.45 on Delphi Xe2, Win 7 it worked by opening install.bat, but now on Win8 , Delphi XE3 it doesn't work... Please somebody advise me how to install properly JVCL (I need to modify a project built with XE2 and Jvcl by the day after tomorrow).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems more likely to be a win8 issue than related to xe3

Comment: Did you try **Run as Administrator** on `install.bat`?

Comment: @LightBulb Hello, I did that but still the same results; I also think that it might be a issue of win 8; the thing is that I don't want to reinstall my os; I will try today to  set up a virtual machine and I hope that I will install JVCL; If somebody comes with another idea I will be thankfull; best regards

Comment: I found the issue; the thing was that my XE3 was a trial version and in trial delphi xe3 doesn't have command line compiler, which is required by jcvl to install; Could JVCL be installed without the command line compiler?

Comment: You could compile it all manually rather than scripting. But why don't you get a real XE3? That's the obvious solution.

Comment: @David Heffernan , I installed JVCL in XE3, but I am very dissapointed of XE3, because when I try to connect to a MS SQL Server database using DBX an error pops up saying that the driver is not properly installed, or missing. I reinstalled Delphi XE3, and also asked a friend of mine to test it and the error is the same. Does somebody has an ideea on how to solve it?

Comment: That's a very different question.

Comment: I will write another question right now;

Comment: For the record: one could just compile the installer - and afterthat procced with scripting :-)